# sintaxe passar valor via post razor asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Estou tentando fazer um metodo de alterar via POST no meu codigo e está dando erro de sintaxe, faço da seguinte forma:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(" ", "Usuario", new
                                {
                                    item.CodigoUsuario
                                }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "div-usuario-index", HttpMethod = "POST" }, new { @class = "editar btn btn-sm btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-edit", @name = "command:alterar" })
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ClearModelState]
        [CommandName("Alterar", "command:alterar")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> AlterarAsync(UsuarioViewModel model)
        {


            model = await this.BuscarUsuarioAsync(model.CodigoUsuario);
            try
            {
                var pessoaFisica = await this.PessoaApplicationService.BuscarPessoaCompletaPorCNPJCPFAsync(model.NumeroCpf);
                pessoaFisica = pessoaFisica ?? new PessoaFisica();

                model.NomeCompleto = pessoaFisica.NomeCompleto;
                model.NumeroCpf = pessoaFisica.NumeroCpf;
                model.NumeroTelefone = pessoaFisica.NumeroTelefone;
                model.DescricaoEndereco = pessoaFisica.DescricaoEndereco;
                model.NomeMunicipio = pessoaFisica.NomeMunicipio;

                model.DescricaoSenha = string.Empty;
                model.RepetirSenha = string.Empty;

                model.RepetirSenha = model.DescricaoSenha;
                ModelState.Remove("DescricaoSenha");
                ModelState.Remove("RepetirSenha");
                Session["Id"] = pessoaFisica.Id;
                return View("Alterar", model);
            }
            catch (BusinessException ex)
            {

                Session["Id"] = model.CodigoUsuario;
                HandleBusinessException(ex);
                return View("Alterar", model);
            }
        }
```

Alguem sabe de que maneira posso fazer isso ?

Comment: Tem pouca informação, em qual momento acontece o erro?

Comment: na hora de compilar ja diz que a sintaxe está incorreta

Comment: Mas em qual linha essa ai ?

Comment: Alterei a forma como passo no razor e na controller, editei o post com as alterações, agora eu clico em alterar e nada acontece....